# Group logged page views into visits

Tags: mysql

I have a table where i track all page views my visitors does on my website. Now I’m trying to get the page views grouped in visits. One visit is done by the same visitorid and if two page views is more than 60 minutes apart I define it as two separate visits. pageviewID is just a random

```
Id  visitorid   timestamp   page
1   1   2013-10-10 18:00    /
2   2   2013-10-10 18:10    /
3   2   2013-10-10 18:12    /about
4   1   2013-10-10 18:14    /contact
5   3   2013-10-10 18:34    /
6   3   2013-10-10 18:37    /contact
7   4   2013-10-10 20:12    /
8   1   2013-10-10 20:14    /about
```

I would like to be able to query for example the last 5 whole visits and get a result as something like this:

```
Id  visitorid   timestamp   page    visitid
1   1   2013-10-10 18:00    /           1
4   1   2013-10-10 18:14    /contact    1
2   2   2013-10-10 18:10    /           2
3   2   2013-10-10 18:12    /about      2
5   3   2013-10-10 18:34    /           3
6   3   2013-10-10 18:37    /contact    3
7   4   2013-10-10 20:12    /           4
8   1   2013-10-10 20:14    /about      5
```

How to do this? I don’t know where to start building the query. I hope I included enough information!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this. SQL works on sets of things, all at the same time. You get some set of rows and act on them to change the information or get different information or to get a summary of the information. What you want to do inherently requires that one iterate through the items one by one. SQL does not do anything one by one. It just will not do that.

I think you need to get the information out of the database into some other tool. Then do something that iterates. Then you can save the new information and do database stuff again.

Say that you had:

```
 Id  visitorid   timestamp   page    visitid
 1   1   2013-10-10 18:00    /           1
 4   1   2013-10-10 18:14    /contact    1
 2   2   2013-10-10 18:10    /           2
 3   2   2013-10-10 19:12    /about      2
 5   2   2013-10-10 19:17    /contact    2
```

You could get the data out and pass it into a perl script or any other script. You could even do it in awk if you had to. The script would iterate through the rows. It would look at the times, in order, of a visitid. If there is an interval between two times greater than an hour, it would create a new visitid and set subsequent requests to that id. The data would become:

```
 Id  visitorid   timestamp   page    visitid
 1   1   2013-10-10 18:00    /           1
 4   1   2013-10-10 18:14    /contact    1
 2   2   2013-10-10 18:10    /           2
 3   2   2013-10-10 19:12    /about      101
 5   2   2013-10-10 19:17    /contact    101
```

For each point it finds where an hour has elapsed, your script could generate SQL which says:

```
update mytable set visitid = 101 where visitId = 2 and timestamp >= '2013-10-10 19:12';
```

You could generate a SQL command like this each time there is an interval greater than an hour, even when there are multiple gaps in one visitid.

Pass that SQL back into your database. And then you can do a normal query in your database.

The other option is to have the thing that is originally recoding the information notice that there has been an hour gap and go to a new visitid, if the visit is defined and the visitid is being recorded at this time.

The short answer is that SQL by itself cannot do everything. This is why, for example, the PL/SQL language in Oracle was defined. It works with database rows, but allows you to do things like iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this using [SQLite window function](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/windowfunctions.html), which can work around the "iteration" part Ray Kiddy describes.

Assuming you have your timestamps as simple unix timestamps, this will calculate the inactive time between each page view of each visitor:

```
SELECT
  utc_time,
  visitor_id,
  -- The window function: resolves the expression for the preceding row of the current partition
  LAG(utc_time) OVER (
    -- The window defition: Partitions all rows per visitor_id and orders each partition's rows by timestamps
    PARTITION BY visitor_id
    ORDER BY
      utc_time
  ) -- Substract the utc_time of the current row from the utc_time of the preceding row to get the time between rows
  - utc_time AS inactivity_time
FROM page_view
ORDER BY
  visitor_id,
  utc_time;
```

The result of the above query can be used to actually assign session ids by a subsequent query. Using those rows where the inactive time is greater than your desired threshold or NULL if it is the first session, you can use yet another window function (row_number) to uniquely identify session, including there start time and the start time of the next session:

```
SELECT
  -- Calculate the session id based on the visitor and the consecutive row number (we only handle session starts here)
  page_view.visitor_id || '-' || row_number() OVER(
    PARTITION BY page_view.visitor_id
    ORDER BY
      page_view.utc_time
  ) AS session_id,
  page_view.visitor_id,
  page_view.utc_time AS session_start_at,
  lead(utc_time) OVER(
    PARTITION BY page_view.visitor_id
    ORDER BY
      page_view.utc_time
  ) AS next_session_start_at
FROM (...) AS page_view
WHERE
  -- Filter for page views with an inactivity time greater 30 mins, these are session starts
  ABS(page_view.inactivity_time) > 30 * 60
  OR page_view.inactivity_time IS NULL;
```

Given that, you might want to store the result in a temporary table to keep things clear.

Assuming the result is stored in a table "session", you can finally calculate some useful stats by joining page views with their corresponding sessions:

```
SELECT
  session_id,
  -- calculate the session duration
  ABS(
    MIN(page_view.utc_time) - MAX(page_view.utc_time)
  ) AS duration,
  -- show distinct paths per session
  COUNT(DISTINCT page_view.path)
FROM session
LEFT JOIN page_view ON page_view.visitor_id = session.visitor_id
  AND page_view.utc_time >= session.session_start_at
  AND (
    page_view.utc_time < session.next_session_start_at
    OR session.next_session_start_at IS NULL
  )
GROUP BY
  1
```

I recommend starting off with the first query and working your way up, that helped me understand what's going on.

Most queries listed here originate from this [blog post](https://statsbot.co/blog/event-analytics-define-user-sessions-sql/), I slightly adjusted them to work in SQLite.